# What is the data type from the source of an image

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flash-builder

another flashbuilder brainbreaker for me...

I have a class with a contstructor that should only change the source of an image.

```
    [Bindable]
    [Embed(source='../pictures/test.jpg')]
    private var _picture:Class; 

    public function Test(newSource:*****)
    {
        _picture.source = newSource;
    }
```

(the image is not an image, but a class, I am aware of this, it is meant to be so :-) )

The problem is that when I call the constructor, let's say:

```
var test:Test = new Test(pictureAtStage.source);
```

Flashbuilder will give an error, becouse I can't tell the compiler what data type "newSource" at the constructor will have...

*edit:
When i use _picture.source, the embedded source does not seem to be changed...?

Anyone knows an answer?

Comment: Ok, no need to answer this question: Setting the data type to Object did the trick... (I will post the answer in eight hours... since I'm new to stackoverflow I can't answer my onwn questions within 8 hours)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are we talking about `mx.controls.Image`? if so, then the source of an image can be: a Class, a Bitmap (not a BitmapData), a String (in which case it is assumed that you wanted to load it instead of using an embedded one). If you want to find a common denominator for all these, then Object is that class, however, I would rather limit it to something particular to your use case.

However, if I may advise anything... don't use `mx.controls.Image`, it's too bloated, even for Flex framework. If it must be a UIComponent - extend UIComponent and let the source be of type BitmapData - this way you will be able to manage resources better - you could reuse the same actual image for example. You could then use `graphics` property of the control to display the image.

Another advise, if you are still here :) Don't use `[Bindable]`, especially the short version of it, especially not on a private variable - you will save yourself the frustration of countless hours of debugging it... Besides, in your case you aren't going to change the value of that variable anyway...

Are you still here? Well, don't use `[Embed]` on variables, use it on class definition - slightly more work for you, but this will, potentially, make your code more portable. If you embed on class the compiler will not generate a silly "something-something-Asset" class, it will use Bitmap or BitmapData - whichever your class extends. Thus, you will not introduce a dependency on Flex framework, and, in general, you will have more control over your code.

**EDIT:** the above was written assuming that _picture (class) variable and _picture (some variable used in a function) are not the same thing. But if they are the same thing, then `Class` class is dynamic, which means that you can add to it properties at runtime (don't know why, it's a design decision by Adobe...), however, the compiler will act as if it's not possible, so you would work around that by adding the property through reflection:

```
var _picture:Class = Sprite;
_picture["source"] = whatever;
trace(Sprite["source"]);
```

Comment: The goal I'm trying to reach is to add my own custom bullets to a AMChart. You can find an example of this here: http://flex.amcharts.com/lib/examples/customBulletsV4.mxml
It seems that the custom bullet here is a class (that is embedded with a *.swf source) so I figured my "custom bullet" must also be a class...

Comment: The dataprovider for the graph is a list with my own defined classes (so _picture is an element (variable) of this class), an searches for the getter that gives the picture (in this case i made the getter return a Class)

Comment: That's the thing: I don't want the "custombullet" to be embedded, because it needs to be chosen per element in the graph by the user...     I've tried to create the _picture class in that way that the "image source" can be read. So far I didn't succeed in creating the _picture Class look like a Class that was embedded... I think I need to set the bitmapdata from the class in order to change the picture (bullet)

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed slightly confusing, It will be of the type `BitmapAsset` which extends `Bitmap`. So any of those will work.

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm very new to flashbuilder I didn't see the obvious solutions...

The solution for the first part of my question (before the edit):
Setting the data type to Object did the trick:

```
[Bindable]
[Embed(source='../pictures/test.jpg')]
private var _picture:Class; 

public function Test(newSource:Object)
{
    _pucture.source = newSource;
}
```